# Button text disappears after setting text colors

Tags: android

My buttons use two XML files to do some fancy color switching when pressed, but I have a problem with the color drawable (dunno what to call it)...

Here's a button

```
<Button
        android:background="@drawable/main_loginbtn"
        android:textColor="@color/main_loginbtn"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:onClick="login"
        android:text="Login" />
```

(I know I shouldn't use hardcoded strings, but I will change this later :)

Here's @drawable/main_loginbtn

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
        <stroke android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#00BFFF"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#00BFFF"/>
        <stroke android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

And finally, here's the @color/main_loginbtn file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#00BFFF"/>
<item android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
</selector>
```

If I remove the textColor reference to @color/main_loginbtn, it will fix the problem and the text will reappear on the button (in black of course). So i'm pretty sure the problem is in the color drawable.

Normally, I wouldn't care about this, but it messes up the scaling on some buttons because of wrap_content, when there's no text inside the buttons.

Thanks for your time!

---

**UPDATE**

I tried creating a second random color drawable, and tested it on a TextView's textColor attribute, and the same problem arose... The entire TextView text disappeared.

So i'm thinking it's a problem with the selector?

Oh, and I also messed up in this question: Nothing "disappears" per say, but rather I can't see the text in the eclipse layout UI. When I run it in the emulator, everything works fine...

Comment: By "Disappear" do you mean that the text is the same color as the rectangle solid color in the editor? If so, try cleaning the project and/or explicitly setting the button state.

Comment: @SoundConception By "disappear" I mean that the text is just gone in the eclipse layout UI editor... But not in the actual emulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the transparency of your color.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#FF00BFFF"/>
    <item android:color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
</selector>
```

The UI editor is assuming your colors are transparent if you don't (in other words it's defaulting to alpha = 00 if you don't set it).